# Solving a system of simultaneous trigonometric equations to find maxima of 4-D scalar field

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, scalar-fields

I have a 4-D scalar field over the $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ axes:

$$X = \cos(A-B) + \cos(A-D) + \cos(C-B) - \cos(C-D)$$

and I want to find the global maxima and minima. I did

$$\nabla X = [-\sin(A-B) - \sin(A-D)]\hat a + [\sin(A-B) + \sin(C-B)]\hat b + [-\sin(C-B) + \sin(C-D)]\hat c + [\sin(A-D) -\sin(C-D)]\hat d$$

Where $\hat a$, $\hat b$, $\hat c$, and $\hat d$ are the unit vectors in each direction. I then set each term in square brackets to zero in order to find out what the critical points are (second-derivative tests can come later):

$$\sin(A-B) + \sin(A-D) = 0$$
$$\sin(A-B) + \sin(C-B) = 0$$
$$\sin(C-D) - \sin(C-B) = 0$$
$$\sin(A-D) - \sin(C-D) = 0$$

An obvious solution is each variable being an integer multiple of π:

$$A = nπ$$
$$B = mπ$$
$$C = pπ$$
$$D = qπ$$

Where $n$, $m$, $p$, and $q$ can each independently be any integer (positive, negative or 0).

However, I found out through numerical simulations that $X$ can reach a maximum value of $2\sqrt{2}$. It is clear that the above integer-π solutions can't possibly make $X$ take on this value. My question is: how do I find out what the other solutions are to those four equations, **analytically**?

Comment: Is it $\color{red}{+}\cos (C-D)$ in the last term?

Comment: Nope, it's definitely a negative sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \cos (A-B)+\cos(A-D) &= 2\cos \frac{B-D}{2} \cos \frac{2A-B-D}{2} \\
  \cos (C-B)-\cos(C-D) &= 2\sin \frac{B-D}{2} \sin \frac{2C-B-D}{2} \\
  X &= R\sin \left( \frac{B-D}{2}+\theta \right) \\
  R^2 &= 4\cos^2 \frac{2A-B-D}{2}+4\sin^2 \frac{2C-B-D}{2} \\
  &= 2[2+\cos (2A-B-D)-\cos (2C-B-D)] \\
\end{align*}

For maximal $R^2$,
\begin{align*}
   2A-B-D &= 2n\pi \\
  2C-B-D &= (2m+1)\pi \\
  X &= 2\left[(-1)^n\cos \frac{B-D}{2}+(-1)^m\sin \frac{B-D}{2} \right] \\
  &= 2\sqrt{2}
     \sin \left[
            (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2}
          \right]
\end{align*}

For maximal $X$,
\begin{align*}
  (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2} &= \frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2} \\
  (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{2}+(-1)^{n} (B-D) &= (4k+1)\pi \\
\end{align*}

For minimal $X$,
\begin{align*}
  (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2} &= \frac{(4k+3)\pi}{2} \\
  (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{2}+(-1)^{n} (B-D) &= (4k+3)\pi \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Oosh, this is a lot more hairy than I bargained for, thanks a lot! Just to clarify: are the conditions for maximum and minimum X both relying on R^2 having already been maximized?

Comment: Yes, absolute maximum or minimum implies the amplitude (magnitude) to be maximized.

Comment: Oh one final thing, how did you go from the $X=2[...]$ step to the $X=2\sqrt{2}[...]$ step (the line preceding "for maximal X")? I recognize use of the $a\cos(x) +b\sin(x) = R\sin(x-\theta)$ relation, where $\tan(\theta) = \frac{b}{a}$, which is where the $\frac{\pi}{4}$ comes from, but I can't figure out how it interacts with the $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^m$ terms. In particular, how does the $\frac{B-D}{2}$ term acquire a $(-1)^n$ coefficient? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: $\tan^{-1} (.) $ is troublesome.  Let's do it backward,
\begin{align*}
  & \quad \sin \left[ (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2} \right] \\ &= \sin\left[ (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4} \right] \cos \left[(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2} \right]+\cos\left[ (-1)^{m}\frac{\pi}{4} \right] \sin \left[(-1)^{n} \frac{B-D}{2} \right] \\ &= \frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2}} \cos \frac{B-D}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \times (-1)^n \sin \frac{B-D}{2} \end{align*} $\sin (.)$ is an odd function so $\sin (\pm x)=\pm \sin x$ whereas $\cos (.)$ is an even function so $\cos (\pm x)=\cos x$.